# XmlReader only reads the first Node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have this XML-File:

```
<StaticHeader>
  <Byte Range="0">
    <Val></Val>
    <Descr>Foobar</Descr>
  </Byte>
  <Byte Range="1">
    <Val></Val>
    <Descr>Bar</Descr>
  </Byte>
  <Byte Range="2">
    <Val></Val>
    <Descr>Foo></Descr>
  </Byte>
</StaticHeader>
```

My code to read this is:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(pathToFile, readerSettings);
reader.MoveToContent();
reader.ReadStartElement();
writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
```

the test output is always:

```
<Byte Range="0">
  <Val></Val>
  <Descr>Foobar</Descr>
</Byte>
```

but I need all contents between `<StaticHeader> and </StaticHeader>`

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `XElement` to you?

Comment: _I need all contenten between ..._  - then you will need some sort of loop

Comment: it is because that ReadStartElement reads the first element, try and load it into a Xdocument, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 that gives  you some more easy and flexible reading. :)

Comment: If you'd like to share the code that you used to solve your problem, we'd love to see it, but please add it as an answer, rather than editing it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
var doc = XElement.Load(pathToFile);
var ranges = doc.Elements("Byte");
```

Comment: Good answer, @GrayFox, if you don't need to use XmlReader and can switch to XElement, I definitely would.

Comment: @Grayfox: I would advise you to use XElement as well since XmlReader will have problems when you have comments in your XML file. So, if you want to write a safe code go for XElement

Comment: Hey, I need to write it back to another XML-File. If I use your way, it inserts StaticHeader, too. How can I avoid this?                  var doc = XElement.Load(pathToFile);
                doc.WriteTo(writer);

Comment: You will need a root element around the <Byte> s. Edit the question to explain the desired result.

Comment: @Meghaa XmlReader has no problem with comments, it reads them fine when set to not ignore them, and ignores them fine when set to do so. There are pros and cons to XElement and XmlReader, but comments isn't relevant to them.

Answer (score 0):

try using while(reader.Read())

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create("[path to your xml file]");
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInnerXml().ToString());
}
```